# Can .NET memory leak cause port exhaustion?

Tags: port, windows-server-2008, c#, iis-7

Our web server has been having an issue due to port exhaustion. This happens every 2 weeks and a reboot fixes the issue. But I want to get to the bottom of this issue and find a permanent fix to avoid the reboots.

I read [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend/) and it was really useful. However, it mentions this:

> So, if you see a process that’s using up a lot of ports, talking to a single remote address or several remote addresses, and the state of the connection is something like TIME_WAIT, that’s usually a dead giveaway that this process is having a problem and **not releasing those ports properly**.

(Emphasis Mine)

Then further down there is this paragraph:

> I mentioned above that memory leaks can cause this behavior too – why is that exactly? What happens is that in order to get a port to use for an outbound connection, processes need to acquire a handle to that port. That handle comes out of non-paged pool memory. So, if you have a memory leak, and you run out of non-paged pool, processes that need to talk to other machines on the network won’t be able to get the handle, and therefore won’t be able to get the port they need.

**Questions**:

1. What does the author mean by *not releasing those ports properly*? Whose job is that, the programmer?
2. Can someone please elaborate how a memory leak could cause *port exhaustion* because I am still not sure after reading the above?

One last thing to keep in mind is that I am a programmer and not an admin (if that helps in anyway possible).

Comment: Should I have posted this question somewhere else (some other site)? Please let me know because I need to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is a programmer's job.
2. Yes, memory leak may cause that. The issue is if the socket was not [closed explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k(v=vs.110).aspx) it only closes when instance of a Socket or other deriving class is [destoyed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx). This is done by [garbage collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) automatically, however it will not destroy the instance of a class if there is at least one reference left somewhere (memory leak).

It may be quite tricky to find out what keeps references to instances and causes the memory leak. It could be threads that are still running and keep references in their local variables. It could be some kind of an array that is used to keep track of all connections. There are a lot of possibilities and they all depend on implementation.

Comment: My question is not about memory leak or how to avoid it. It is about how a memory leak can result in port exhaustion.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, let me rephrase then. The port is not getting freed if the socket associated with that port is not closed explicitly and the class that uses it is still in memory due to a memory leak. And there is a limited number of ports that may be open at the same time.